# What is a proper translation of the Cole Porter song title "Begin the Beguine"?

Tags: traducción, letras-de-canciones

I've seen the Cole Porter song title, "Begin the Beguine" translated into Spanish as "Volver a Empezar". http://lyrics.wikia.com/Julio_Iglesias:Volver_A_Empezar

"Beguine," in English is a dance. "Volver a Empezar" means something like "Lets's Go Back to the Beginning," not "Let's Begin the Dance."

What would be the purpose of translating "Begin the Beguine" as Volver a Empezar? Perhaps it has something to do with the Spanish lyrics, which begin "Quiero sentir, las cosas de siempre"? (I don't know the rest of it.)

Comment: Sounds like it's just a mistranslation, or they decided "beguine" was too obscure for a Spanish speaking audience and went for a non literal translation in this case based on a similar sounding word.

Comment: @hippietrail: Why don't you post your comment as an anwer

Comment: Mainly because it's just an opinion I can't back up and I personally don't like opinions as answers on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Is your question, "What is the proper translation of "Begin the Beguine", or "What would be the purpose of translating "Begin the beguine" as "Volver a Empezar"?. One of those questions is answerable - the other is quite subjective.

Comment: @razlebe: I'd say the question is, is "Volver a Empiezar" a "plausible" translation of the song title, even allowing for some poetic license.

Comment: That sounds like a much better wording for the question. Sorry if it sounds like I'm being picky, but so far you have two answers for two different questions. :)

Comment: @hippietrail: creo que mas que opiniones no se pueden dar a esta pregunta, a no ser que encontremos al que tradujo la canción ;)

Comment: I suggest that "Begin the Beguine" in English was a play on words.  It's not enough to translate the title.  One has to attempt to capture the flavor of the original wordplay.  I can't improve on "Volver a Empezar".

Comment: @WalterMitty What play on words??

Comment: There is a play on the similar sound between the verb "begin" and the noun "beguine".  It's not a pun, but it is wordplay.  I can't think of a translation that doesn't lose this feature of the original.

Comment: What wordplay? It is just alliteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the translation to "Volver a Empezar" was made to mantain the sense of the original title: "Begin the Beguine" here, if you pronounce the title you have something like "begin the begin" like "comenzar el comienzo".

Comment: No, begin and beguine are not pronounced in the same way **at all**.

Answer (score 7):

The original "translation" by María Grever (which appeared on the sheet music back in the '30s, along with Cole Porter's English lyrics) doesn't have all that much to do with the English lyrics. Lyrics websites being generally pretty horrible I don't want to link to one, but you can find them by searching for something like `Jorge-Negrete Begin-the-beguine`.

The version you've come across appears to be the "new" (1981) "translation" by Julio Iglesias which also has little to do with the English lyrics, apart from containing the English title twice. However, every stanza ends with either *Quiero volver a empezar* or *Para volver a empezar*, so it's a logical title.

Whether the origin was Julio Iglesias' misunderstanding of Cole Porter's lyrics or a deliberate play on words is something which you'd have to ask him (or find discussed in an interview), and even then I don't know how you'd know whether he was telling the truth.

Answer (score 3):

> Comienza el baile

Given that "beguine" is a dance.

Comment: See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beguine_(dance)

Comment: @CesarGon There is a mistake in your link, the second **)** should be in the link too :)

Comment: @Alenanno: You are right. I pasted the link straight into the comment edit box and that's the outcome. As far as I know, I can't change it now. :-( The correct link is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beguine_(dance)).

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that the right translation for "begin the beguine" is: "Comenzar el beguine" meaning the beguine the popular dance from Martinica and Guadalupe Caribbean islands. The evidence is that there's a verse ahead in the lyrics of Cole Porter's song saying: "oh yes, let them begin the beguine make them play". Of course, "them" are the musicians of an orchestra playing a piece with a beguine rhythm.

Comment: Can you say why you think that the accepted answer is wrong? It seems much more likely to me that this is an attempt to reproduce the play on words of the English version.